# ORACLE is QUOTA required?

Tags: oracle, quota, tablespace

I have a quick question about assigning quotas to users on tablespaces. Does a user require quota in order to select, update and insert data into a table stored in x tablespace? Do I need to grant that user quota on that x tablespace?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The schema needs a quota, explicit or unlimited, in order to be able to create objects within that tablespace, such as tables and indexes.

It is the owner of the table who needs the quota, not the user who modifies it by adding rows.